# reactjs Input onChange switchRoute but lost first character

Tags: reactjs

I try to build some "google-like-search-imput" page - on input change, switch to the result page and show all search results.

But if i press any key - I jump to the results page (#/results) and i lost my first entered character?

Has anyone an hint, how I can fix this?

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      query: ''
    };
    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
  }
  updateInputValue(event) {
    this.setState({query: event.target.value});
    console.log('event ' + event.target.value);
    this.props.history.push('/search');
    // history.push('/search')
    // this.context.router.push('/');
  }

  render() {
    var query = this.state.query;
    return (
      <article>
        <SearchForm query={query} onChange={this.updateInputValue} />
      </article>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because when you do `this.props.history.push('/search');` Home component unmounts and you lose the state. You need to store `query` in some external state like redux or if you use React-Router 4 you can also do it with [location state.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)